# How do I display a custom checkout field on my custom page within the Wordpress dashboard?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the Checkout Field Editor for WooCommerce plugin on a wordpress site to add custom fields to the Woocommerce checkout page.
They appear normally, all right, they also appear normally on the orders page within the Woocommerce panel itself.

What I want is:

I have a custom page that I am making inside the panel to display display all orders (I need this page for my project).

In it I am able to get all the data for each order, using the code below. How can I get the value of the custom field I created using the plugin mentioned above? Is there a possibility?

Below is the code I am using on this page to obtain the information for each order.

```
$order_id  = $order->get_id();
$billing_country = $order->get_billing_country();
$billing_first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name()
```

Comment: Most likely the plugin is saving data as meta against the order. So `$order->get_meta( 'some_custom_field', true )` would get you the value of the order's `some_custom_field` key. You'll need to find out how the checkout field plugin saves the data. I don't have the plugin on hand so can't check.

Comment: And maybe not useful since you are using the Checkout Field Editor, but I've written a pretty extensive tutorial on how to add fields to the checkout: https://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/